# How to remove dynamically created controls?

Tags: vb.net, loops, dynamic, controls

I've added a few pictureboxes to my form with:

At the top of code:

```
Private Flag As PictureBox
```

Under the form1_Load event:

```
Flag.Location = New Point(buttonX, buttonY)
                        Flag.BackColor = Color.Red
                        Flag.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                        Flag.Name = "Flag" & Pos
                        Me.TabPage1.Controls.Add(Flag)
                        Flag.BringToFront()
```

So I end up with, for example, 4 pictureboxes named "Flag2" "Flag5" "Flag6" "Flag8".  I then try to remove them all with:

```
Dim con As Control
        For Each con In Me.TabPage1.Controls
            If con.Name.Contains("Flag") Then
                Me.TabPage1.Controls.Remove(con)
            End If
        Next
```

What ends up happening is not all the pictureboxes are deleted.  If I run the delete code multiple times it will get rid of them all but I'm trying to remove them all at once.  I also tried:

```
Dim con As Control
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < Me.TabPage1.Controls.Count
            con = Me.TabPage1.Controls(i)
            If con.Name.Contains("Flag") Then
                Me.TabPage1.Controls.Remove(con)
            End If
            i += 1
        End While
```

Both "Delete Codes" delete the picture boxes in the same order as each other (Not in the order created by the way) instead of deleting all of the picture boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
'create the pbs to delete
Dim pbs = Me.TabPage1.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)().
             Where(Function(pb) pb.Name.Contains("Flag"))
'loop thru them
For Each pb In pbs
  Me.TabPage1.Controls.Remove(pb)
Next
```

Sub:

```
Public Sub RemovePictureBoxes(tp As TabPage)
  'create the pbs to delete
  Dim pbs = tp.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)().
             Where(Function(pb) pb.Name.Contains("Flag"))
  'loop thru them
  For Each pb In pbs
    tp.Controls.Remove(pb)
  Next  
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
RemovePictureBoxes(TabPage1)
```

Comment: I assume the "'create the pbs to delete" code would be declared globally because I am creating/ deleting in separate functions.  I get the following error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I used the code you gave me incorrectly.  I tried the function you suggested and the result was the same as the two I tried.  What I noticed though (and this happened with my code too I just didn't notice) is that it's every other box that is being deleted.  Each time I run the code it deletes the last one created and every other one from there.  So if I've got 10 boxes I have to run the code 4 times for all of them to be  deleted.  I'm sure this isn't the best way to got about it though.  Any thoughts?

Comment: That does not make sense. It should remove them all. Did you debug and check the variables and step thru the code to see what it's doing?

Comment: I think removing the `Private Flag As PictureBox` declaration would be better and just declare a new `PictureBox` when you do so.

Comment: I stepped through your code with a breakpoint on "tp.Controls.Remove(pb)".  It never passes over the ones that should  be deleted but are not.  I read this on another forum of a similar issue: "The "every other one" effect is because there is no current btn when it gets to
the Next, so the next btn becomes the current btn, and the one after that
becomes the next btn. It is generally true of collections."  I don't fully understand it but would it help? Source: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/771891-controls-remove-not-removing-all-controls

Comment: Not a valid comparison. They were iterating the collection directly. I am iterating a List that I made and asking the collection to remove an object it contains. This is a safe remove process. There must be something else bugging it up.

Comment: I stepped through your code again and I noticed that "pbs" does contain all of the objects I'm trying to delete.  So it's not a matter of finding them.  I'm thinking that it must have something to do with For Each...Next bit  but I don't see where that could go wrong.

Comment: You could try my method without the Where predicate and see if that works - as long as there are no other PBs that are supposed to be left behind.

Comment: Same result unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using a loop back to start to restart when it hangs.It includes additional code to delete the file that may not be necessary.
This is using a Flowlayout Panel but the code gives you the idea.

```
start:
For Each Control In Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
  If TypeOf Control Is PictureBox Then Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(Control)
  If IO.File.Exists(Control.tag.ToString) then                  
    IO.File.Delete(Control.Tag.ToString)
    Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(Control)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    Control.image = Nothing
    Control.Dispose()
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Refresh()
  End If
Next Control
If FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count > 0 Then GoTo start
```